# War FTP 550 Access Denied

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

I'm running a data server with `Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard` and trying to use `WarFTP` server. I know nothing about server maintenance and just took over maintenance last week. I am trying to setup a new account on the server for FTP access. Seeing as how I know nothing about servers, I simply looked at the information in the users list for another account and tried to copy that exactly to create a new account.

With the new account I am able to connect via `Filezilla`, but when I try to upload I get:

> Status:   Resolving address of domain
>   Status: Connecting to 555.555.5.555:21...
>   Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>   Response:   220-Server domain
>   Response:       WarFTPd 1.82.00-RC11 (Sep 22 2006) Ready
>   Response:       (C)opyright 1996 - 2006 by Jarle (jgaa) Aase - all rights reserved.
>   Response:   220 Please enter your user name.
>   Command:    USER USER
>   Response:   331 User name okay, need password.
>   Command:    PASS ******
>   Response:   230 Welcome to ServerUser USER logged in from host 55-55-555-55.static.hckr.nc.comcast.com (96.36.125.34)
>   Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
>   Status: Connected
>   Status: Starting upload of C:\Users\Default\Desktop\video_file.mp4
>   Command:    CWD /
>   Response:   250 "/": is current directory.
>   Command:    TYPE I
>   Response:   200 Type set to I.
>   Command:    PASV
>   Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (173,234,9,170,50,164)
>   Command:    STOR video_file.mp4
>   Response:   550 Access denied.
>   Error:  Critical file transfer error

The other accounts that were already up there work just fine. It's the new one that I can't upload with.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.